# Is there any way by which we can change the number of target classes in multi-class classification problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have a text dataset with 13 classes. There are some classes which are overlapping. However, to prove that these classes are overlapping, I wish to train a machine learning classifier on the data with 13 labels and then test it on fewer labels say 10,11 etc to find the what is the minimum number of non-overlapping target labels would be there in the dataset.

Please tell how can I change the number of taget labels while testing a classifier?

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way to find overlapping classes is to train your machine learning classifier with all the 13 classes and plot a confusion matrix like this on the test set(using matplotlib).
For example - Your confusion matrix looks like this. Here you can see that class 0 and 3 looks like overlapping classes because miss classification between them is high.
So, in this way you can find out overlapping classes.

[image]